# Accessing CDATA values in a simplexmliterator

Tags: php, simplexml, cdata

I have a simple xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fmxmlsnippet type="FMObjectList">
    <Step enable="True" id="141" name="Set Variable">
        <Value>
            <Calculation><![CDATA[Get(RecordID)]]></Calculation>
        </Value>
        <Repetition>
            <Calculation><![CDATA[1]]></Calculation>
        </Repetition>
        <Name>$currentRecord</Name>
    </Step>
</fmxmlsnippet>
```

What I'm trying to do is pull out the attribute values for the `Step` node as well as the CDATA values form the `Calculation` child node for the `Value` and `Repetition` nodes.

I can get the step attribute values without an issue:

```
$iterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);

for($iterator->rewind() ; $iterator->valid() ; $iterator->next()){
     $stepId = $iterator->current()->attributes()->id->__toString();
     $stepName = $iterator->current()->attributes()->name->__toString();
     $stepEnable= $iterator->current()->attributes()->enable->__toString();
}
```

But I'm having a problem getting the CDATA. I've tried numerous methods of getting it without success.

I noticed at one point that when I die and var_dump the result of `$iterator->current()` in my for loop the CDATA doesn't even look like it is recognized:

```
object(SimpleXMLIterator)#3 (4) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["enable"]=>
    string(4) "True"
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "141"
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "Set Variable"
  }
  ["Value"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLIterator)#4 (1) {
    ["Calculation"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLIterator)#6 (0) {
    }
  }
  ["Repetition"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLIterator)#5 (1) {
    ["Calculation"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLIterator)#6 (0) {
    }
  }
  ["Name"]=>
  string(14) "$currentRecord"
}
```

It's like the content of the `Calculation` nodes is empty.

Is there a way of getting the CDATA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that `var_dump()` is just misleading, it shows its empty but its **it is there**. Simply cast it then assign:

```
for($iterator->rewind() ; $iterator->valid() ; $iterator->next()){
     $stepId = $iterator->current()->attributes()->id->__toString();
     $stepName = $iterator->current()->attributes()->name->__toString();
     $stepEnable= $iterator->current()->attributes()->enable->__toString();

     $calculation = (string) $iterator->current()->Value->Calculation;
     $repitition = (string) $iterator->current()->Repetition->Calculation;

     echo $calculation . '<br/>' . $repitition;
}
```

[Sample Output](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ifwmaw)

Comment: Fantastic! I wish I had seen your comment before going to bed last night, it would have saved me some tossing and turning :P I appreciate the help (I didn't know about casting) and also for the link to http://codepad.viper-7.com/ in general, that's a helpful tool!